# uitableviewcell auto layout constraints messed up on viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableViewCell subclass with an image view and a label. I use storyboards with autolayout for prototype cells. The setup is as follows:

```
---------
  |
label
  |
imageView
  |
---------
```

The catch is that on leaving this view (so it disappears) and then returning (appearing again) within a tabBar, the layout gets messed up as if the height constraint of the imageView (which is not defined in the storyboard) has a higher priority, so it shrinks and takes the label with it.

One problem solved!:)
One possible solution is through having the imageView stick just to it's superview, not to the label. That makes the label and imageView independent and practically solves my situation of the imageView shrinking, because it sticks to the top of the contentView pretty well.
It however doesn't solve the situation, when you'd like to expand the label and shrink the imageView accordingly, so it will have to be bound to the imageView.

How can be this done?